# What was the Democrats' counter to REDMAP?

Tags: united-states, democratic-party, gerrymandering

For the 2010 elections, Republicans created the Redistricting Majority Project (REDMAP) with the plan of flipping state legislative chambers to take control of the redistricting process.  Did the Democrats have a similar organization, and if so what was it called?

(Note: I don't consider the DSLC an equivalent group, as the Republicans also had the RSLC in 2010 but that never seems to get mentioned in analysis.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DSLC has launched Advantage 2020, which seeks to be an answer to REDMAP, which will also be launching REDMAP 2020.

More info: http://www.dlcc.org/advantage-2020

Answer (score 4):

There was no such effort in 2010.

While the DLCC is [supporting redistricting efforts](http://www.dlcc.org/redistricting-0), their [Advantage 2020 PAC closed in 2016](https://ballotpedia.org/Advantage_2020).

The current answer to REDMAP 2020 is the [National Democratic Redistricting Committee (NDRC)](https://democraticredistricting.com/), Chaired by Eric Holder. Democratic leaders pitched the NDRC to major donors at the 2016 Democratic National Convention and it launched later that year. The [NDRC has an ongoing partnership with Organizing For Action (OFA)](https://democraticredistricting.com/ofa-and-ndrc-announce-partnership/)—the non-profit founded to support President Barack Obama's policy agenda—and [has Obama's direct support](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YyIWjO94Lnk).

Comment: This answer is more up to date and accurate ^^